# Get rows from table in different orders

Tags: php

The code `While($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))` return rows **1,2,3...n-1,n**.

I need after to get from the same $res (not to make **new query**) the rows but in another order **n,n-1,...,2,1**.

It is possible?

Comment: will be good without reverse array and using of other additional variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_data_seek()` function.

Example:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $query );
$totalRows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows( $result );

for( $i=($totalRows-1); $i>=0; $i-- )
{
    mysqli_data_seek( $result, $i );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
}
```

**Please note:** You can use `mysqli_data_seek` only after `mysqli_query`, `mysqli_store_result` or `mysqli_use_result`.

---

- See more about [mysqli_data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Comment: @Mitch What new query? You say “not to make new query”... In the example there are only a loop, like your `while`, but in reverse order.

Comment: Dear @Mitch, what is more pretty is an opinion. Generally, it is more performant with loop. But if you close this question by accepting an answer and ask for a new question explaining your complete goal (what you desire in original loop and what you desire in additional reverse loop), maybe someone can further improve the performance using only one loop.

Answer (score 2):

Simple juste reverse array and save it in a new variable.

```
<?php

  $newvar=array_reverse($array);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `ORDER BY columnName` in your query, all you have to do is replace it by `ORDER BY columnName DESC`

Comment: Read `not to make new query`.

Comment: I know how to use order by, but I am want to know if it is possible without another query and will be good without reverse array